# Transformers - What happened to Rodimus, Kup & Blurr?

Tags: transformers

In one of the early-ish episodes of Transformers: Headmasters (Japanese series) Rodimus goes off into space with Kup & Blurr to look for a new home for the Autobots. We hear nothing about them from this point on.

What happens to them? They are not referenced in the series that follow - Masterforce, Victory and Zone.

Did they just *really* need to get away from that whining brat Daniel?

Comment: Didn't Hot Rod stay on the planet where they became Targetmasters?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodimus#Marvel_Comics

Comment: @phantom42 The TargetMasters were from Feminia I think, like Wheelie. I don't think they became "TargetMasters" until the explosion that fused the refugees from Planet Master to their arms.
No, Hot Rod/Rodimus didn't go to Planet Master and stay there AFAIK. Otherwise he'd have fought Scorponok when he was there later in the same series.

Comment: This reminds me of the brilliant "Optimus Prime's Rude Awakening"  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bq1_6D9QS9Y